# Concatenate object into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var groupArrays = {
    "group1" : [
        "volvo",
        "bmw",
        "audi"
    ],
    "group2" : [
        "red"
    ],
    "group3" : [
        "1991"
    ]
};
```

This object is created after filtering a list of cars, I would like to create some css selectors with this to use in javascript to show filtered elements. So basically what I want is an array with possible selectors, something like this:

```
var selectors = [".volvo.red.1991", ".bmw.red.1991", ".audi.red.1991"];
```

What's the easiest method here to create the `selectors` array if the number of groups is unknown?

Comment: You'll need to show more data for us to understand what the grouping pattern is.  What does one do if there is more than one item in group2 or group3?  It isn't clear what the algorithm would be for building the selectors.  Are you just trying to build all possible combinations of group1, group2 and group3?

Comment: Continuing that train of thought: What if the user hadn’t selected any brands? I don’t think your problem can be solved elegantly with a few nested loops. If we consider the filter design: Why do we need to select `1991` or `red` three times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var groupArrays = {
    "group1": [
         "volvo",
         "bmw",
         "audi"
     ],
     "group2": [
         "red"
     ],
     "group3": [
         "1991"
     ]
};

var selectors = [];
var selector;

for (var g1 = 0; g1 < groupArrays.group1.length; g1++) {
    for (var g2 = 0; g2 < groupArrays.group2.length; g2++) {
        for (var g3 = 0; g3 < groupArrays.group3.length; g3++) {
            selector = "." + groupArrays.group1[g1] +
                        "." + groupArrays.group2[g2] +
                        "." + groupArrays.group3[g3];
            selectors.push(selector);
        }
    }
}

console.log(selectors);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgN7t/)

Updated code for any number of groups

```
var groupArrays = {
    "group1": [
        "volvo",
        "bmw",
        "audi"
    ],
    "group2": [
        "red","green"
    ],
    "group3": [
        "1991","1992"
    ]
};

var selectors = [];
var values = [];
var ga = [];

for (var group in groupArrays) {
    ga.push(groupArrays[group]);
}

traverse(ga, 0);

console.log(selectors);

function traverse(ga, index) {
    if (index >= ga.length) {
        selectors.push("." + values.join("."));

        return;
    }

    var hold = ga[index].slice(0);
    var gacopy = ga[index];

    while(gacopy.length > 0) {
        var pickedValue = gacopy[gacopy.length - 1];
        values.push(pickedValue);
        gacopy.pop();

        traverse(ga, index + 1);

        values.splice(values.indexOf(pickedValue), 1);
    }

    ga[index] = hold;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KL9G8/)

Comment: The number of groups is unknown

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple series of nested loops will do this. You might have some problems with the *class* `1991` beginning with a number, though.

```
var selectors = [];
var i = groupArrays.group1.length,
    j,
    k;
while (i--) {
    j = groupArrays.group2.length;
    while (j--) {
        k = groupArrays.group3.length;
        while (k--) {
            selectors.push(
                '.' + groupArrays.group1[i] +
                '.' + groupArrays.group2[j] +
                '.' + groupArrays.group3[k]
            );
        }
    }
}
selectors; // [".audi.red.1991", ".bmw.red.1991", ".volvo.red.1991"]
```

If you have an unknown number of items in `groupArrays`, you may need to `for..in` loop over it and recurse with the resulting keys.

Comment: The number of groups is unknown

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function

```
var selectors = [];
groupArrays["group1"].map(function(x) {
    groupArrays["group2"].map(function(y) {
        groupArrays["group3"].map(function(z) {
                    selectors.push('.' + x + '.' + y + '.' + z)})})});
```

Comment: The number of groups is unknown